# Usage of 'that' in place of 'than'

Tags: word-usage, comparisons

Is it right to use 'that' in place of 'than'? 
Eg.football is more popular that cricket.
2.he is better that him.

Comment: Is there any specific reason that makes you think this might be correct? Did you read it somewhere, did someone tell you this? The example sentences you give will _not_ be seen as correct by any native speakers.

Comment: What Ryan & danni said. ie No. Not ever.

Comment: On the other hand, "that" for "than" is an extremely common typographical error—and one that a computer spelling checker may not call out for you because _that_ is a real word. As a result you are very likely to see sentences along the lines of "he is better that him"; but the explanation is, It's a typo.

Comment: It is just as right as using *on* instead of *an*, *as* instead of *is*, and *of* instead of *or*. Is others said, please explain what lakes you thing otherwise. Failing than, the question as rhetorical.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - Yeah, it must be the lakes doing it.

Comment: I've seen use of 'that' inplace of 'than' in some articles and comments(mostly in comparison).i think it's a contraction of "than that" but not sure.

Comment: The explanation for the instances you've seen is likelier that the writer accidentally omitted the word _than_ from a "than that" construction than that [not simply "that"] the writer intended to use _that_ as a contracted form of "than that."

Answer (score 1):

No.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​